# What do the Clustal Alignment Symbols Mean?

Tags: bioinformatics, proteins, homology

Occasionally I will run protein alignments on peptide families and I can never remember what the symbols mean to show degrees of identity. What do they mean?

Answer (score 6):

From the [FAQ for the Clustal-W2](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/msa/clustalw2/help/faq.html#23) program:

> An * (asterisk) indicates positions which have a single, fully conserved residue.
>
> A : (colon) indicates conservation between groups of strongly similar properties - scoring > 0.5 in the Gonnet PAM 250 matrix.
>
> A . (period) indicates conservation between groups of weakly similar properties - scoring =< 0.5 in the Gonnet PAM 250 matrix.

Therefore the hierchy of conservation using these symbols is * (identical) > : (colon) > . (period).